# ember-cli, ember-data, restadapter: change REST host in production?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-cli

I have created my REST host's address as property in
config/environment.js and use it successfully during development.

but once it should go live, the REST server may change and even during the live time of the app the REST server may change to another host.
building via
    ember build -prod ...
puts the variable inside a lengthy string in idex.html and the minified and compacted app-js file, where it cannot be changed easily.

I cannot believe that, I need to re-build the whole app just to change the REST host's address.

**Simple question: How to change the REST host in production easily?**